# how disable button on click when the application first time runs

Tags: java, android

In my application I have 2 buttons.
The first button in start game and the second button in continue game.
I want to disable my second button for the first time when my application runs.
It means just for the first time my second button is disabled to `onClick`. How to handle this?
How can I make it understand it is the first time?

```
public class Menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

SharedPreferences prefs;
Editor edit;
TextView best;
private boolean flag;
public static ImageView btn1, conti, but3, but4;
static Noti_Queue noti_queue;
static Splash splash;
public static AppList applist;
public static int userId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

    flag = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("flag", false);


    if (applist == null) {
        applist = new AppList(this);
        applist.set_identity("1");
    }

    if (splash == null) {
        splash = new Splash(this);
        splash.set_identity("1");
    }

    if (noti_queue == null) {
        noti_queue = new Noti_Queue(this);
        noti_queue.set_identity("1");
    }


    btn1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    conti = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    but3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    but4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    conti.setOnClickListener(this);
    conti.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cont);
    if (!flag) {
        flag = true;
        conti.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cont_press);}
    conti.setEnabled(flag);
    but3.setOnClickListener(this);
    but4.setOnClickListener(this);


    // giving question id
    final int que_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("integer", 0);
    Log.e("mhs", que_id + "");
    //now lets save the que_id(now it is save to SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    userId = myPrefs.getInt("userId", 0);
    //let get it to show

    Log.e("saved", que_id + "");

    setsize();
    best = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
    best.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    edit = prefs.edit();
    if (prefs.getInt("Best", 0) <= 0) {
        edit.putInt("Best", 0);
        edit.commit();
    }
    best.setText("بیشترین امتیاز : " + prefs.getInt("Best", 0));
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    splash.Display();
    splash = null;
    super.onBackPressed();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    best.setText("بیشترین امتیاز : " + prefs.getInt("Best", 0));
    super.onResume();
}

private void setsize() {


    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int h = dm.heightPixels;
    int w = dm.widthPixels;

    h = h / 6;
    w = w - ((w * 30) / 100);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);

    but4.setLayoutParams(params);
    but3.setLayoutParams(params);
    btn1.setLayoutParams(params);
    conti.setLayoutParams(params);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.button1:
            if (!flag) {
                flag = true;
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("flag", flag).commit();
                conti.setEnabled(flag);
                conti.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cont_press);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //finishing this activity is important to exit from app
                Menu.this.finish();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.btn2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userId + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Menu.this, ContinueActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("integer2", userId);
            startActivity(intent1);
            Menu.this.finish();
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "help", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            applist.Display();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: use button.setEnabled(false) in onCreateActivity

Comment: @ManishYadav I think you dont understand my question, I just want just first time

Comment: use button.setEnabled(fa‌​lse) in onCreateActivity and then setEnabled(true) when start button clicked.....

Answer (score 0):

With the help of sharedprefrence you can achieve this for example.

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("enableButton", true);
        editor.commit();
```

put this code for enabling Button.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        flag = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("enableButton", false);
        if (flag) {
           conti.setEnabled(true);  ;
        }
```